# Blurring the launcher widget background

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm working on a clock launcher widget (the one, which is added to a launcher).
I am manually drawing the time on the bitmap, and then do

```
    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);
    AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);

    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
            R.layout.widget_layout);
    // Set the text
    SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", Locale.US);
    remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageView, buildUpdate(context, timeFormat.format(new Date()))); //update imageView with a new bitmap with drawn time
    manager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
```

What I want is to additionally blur the widget's background (the wallpaper under widget).

I know how to blur a bitmap, but this case I don't have a bitmap to blur, since I think I can't get the part of the background under widget.

So is there way to blur the background of the widget?

**Please Note!** I know how to blur the bitmap. But I don't need to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible because there is no way to get widget underlying bitmap to apply blur. You can only create an partly transparent background.

Comment: that is kind of option. But I'll wait a little in case if somebody can offer any kind of hack